# How to get rows collection based on selected cells in DatagridView

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview, selection

I have a DatagridView control on a Windows form. It's selectionMode property is set to CellSelect. 
I want to operate on DatagridViewRow based on selected cells. The DataGridView control is bound to a DataSource.

How to get the Row collection based on selected cells ?

Comment: *Row collection based on Selected cells* ? Can you expand a bit on that, Coz there is a `SelectedCells` collection not sure if you are looking for the same ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
List<DataGridViewRow> rowCollection = new List<DataGridViewRow>();

foreach(DataGridViewCell cell in dataGridView.SelectedCells)
{
    rowCollection.Add(dataGridView.Rows[cell.RowIndex];
}
```

Comment: cell.OwningRow is a bit more direct.

Comment: Right. I didn't know it exists. Thanks

Comment: no problem. Not that there is anything wrong with your answer, it's still very simple!

Comment: I don't understand how this would work, what it a user had multiple cells selected in one row, wouldn't this add the same row twice?

Answer (score 10):

The answer provided as Linq does not work with the syntax provided. Datagridview does not support ienumerable so you have to use:

```
        IEnumerable<DataGridViewRow> selectedRows = dgPOPLines.SelectedCells.Cast<DataGridViewCell>()
                                           .Select(cell => cell.OwningRow)
                                           .Distinct();
```

Answer (score 6):

`DataGridView.SelectedCells` will give you the list of cells that are selected. Each of the `DataGridViewCell` instances in that collection has an `OwningRow`, this allows you to build your own row collection.

For example:

```
using System.Linq;

IEnumerable<DataGridViewRow> selectedRows = dgv.SelectedCells
                                               .Select(cell => cell.OwningRow)
                                               .Distinct();
```

Comment: It could be possible then the same row would be part of the Collection multiple times